# Converting a payload to pdf for viewing via a hyperlink

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, pdf, visual-studio-2015, payload

I want a user to be able to retrieve a payload stored in a database and display it as a pdf by clicking a link. I've never worked with payloads before so I'm starting at square one. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you used Google to try and find a starting point?

Comment: @David yes I've been Googling but nothing seems to be a perfect fit. The upshot of it is that you have to convert a Base64Binary file like this Convert.FromBase64String(myVariable) and then go from there, although some sites say it can be done in Firefox and Google but not IE